# Vaadin maven plugin

Tags: vaadin

Есть один проект и его я переделываю на maven интерфейс реализован на *vaadin* мне надо его поменять на *ext.js*. проблема в том что когда я запускаю
***gwt-maven-plugin*** она не полностью собирается, в логах пишет что бы я исправил `xxxxx.gwt.xml` файл.

`xxxxx.gwt.xml` файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 1.7.0//EN"
            "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.7.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
    <module>
        <!-- Inherit DefaultWidgetSet -->
        <inherits name="com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.DefaultWidgetSet"/>
        <inherits name="com.invient.vaadin.charts.widgetset.InvientChartsWidgetset" />
    </module>
```

при собирании в этот файл maven добавляет `<inherits name="com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet" />` вот такую строчку, в помке все включена но при запуске `Weblogic` ругается вот логи:

```
Error:GWT Compiler: com.vaadin.client.ApplicationConnection cannot be resolved to a type
Error:GWT Compiler: com.vaadin.client.ServerConnector cannot be resolved to a type
Error:GWT Compiler: com.vaadin.client.ui.ui.UIConnector cannot be resolved to a type
Error:GWT Compiler: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<UI> to Class<? extends Connector>
Error:GWT Compiler: com.vaadin.client.ui.VOverlay cannot be resolved to a type
Error:GWT Compiler: com.vaadin.client.ComponentConnector cannot be resolved to a type
Error:GWT Compiler: com.vaadin.client.ui.layout.ElementResizeEvent cannot be resolved to a type
Error:GWT Compiler: com.vaadin.client.HasComponentsConnector cannot be resolved to a type
```

я добавил в помку *validator* от *hibernate* но все равно может кто знает *Vaadin*, что не так?